# Variable(s) missing (use: --variable APP_DOMAIN=value --variable PAGE_LINK_DOMAIN=value

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4, firebase-dynamic-links

I need to set up [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-dynamic-links). I have done it according to the doc. But it shows below error. Can you tell me how to find out these values for my app?

`APP_DOMAIN` and `PAGE_LINK_DOMAIN`

I need to create dynamic links programmatically.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks
> cordova.cmd plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks
Variable(s) missing (use: --variable APP_DOMAIN=value --variable PAGE_LINK_DOMAIN=value).
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a project in Firebase console and create a dynamic link URL there.

Once you create the dynamic link URL, you will have a domain for that. Consider you have purchased a domain `foobar.com` and you have set up a dynamic link in Firebase project with domain `foobar.page.link`, then you have to run this command to install the plugin:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks 
    --variable APP_DOMAIN="foobar.com"
    --variable PAGE_LINK_DOMAIN="foobar.page.link"
```

It's mentioned in the Cordova [plugin doc](https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks#installation):

> Use variable APP_DOMAIN specify web URL where your app will start an
>   activity to handle the link.
>
> Use variable PAGE_LINK_DOMAIN specify your *.page.link domain.
>
> Use variable FIREBASE_DYNAMIC_LINKS_VERSION and
>   FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_VERSION to override dependency version on Android.